# email deliverability

Tags: email, deliverability

How can I enable permissions to edit Email Deliverability access level? Currently it is not editable and in system mode. I need to edit it and set it to "All Email so I can test Approval and workflow functionality. is it restricted to our organization?

Comment: no, I can't edit it, i can't change "Access level", from No access, to all email

Comment: you need to create a salesforce case support ticket.

Comment: where should I do it?

Comment: here [Create a Support Case](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=workcom_contact_support.htm&type=5)

Comment: You must have Customize Application permission